# mongodb BulkWriteResult c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I don't see the property BulkWriteResult in "insertMany" of c# mongodb API.

I need to get nInserted (as a shell operation) from c#.

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the `insertMany` method is a void.

The next best thing would be using the [`BulkWrite`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollectionBase_1_BulkWrite.htm) method which returns a neat [`BulkWriteResult<T>`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_BulkWriteResult.htm)